# Cannot use Redux set Functions in handleChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Can we assign state value into redux?

I just wanted to put selected value into redux so I can access this from the parent component. Is there any other way to access child component selected value. I have redux object but I cannot put data into it from this child component. But ı can use it from parent .Help plz

When I try this. I got an error. something like those;

```
class Dropdown extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: this.props.placeHolder,
            data: [],
            selectedOption: null,
            selectedOption2: null
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleChangeDestination = this.handleChangeDestination.bind(this)
    }
    filterDestinationList(data) {
        if (this.state.selectedOption != null) {
            let filteredData = data.filter(arrayItem => arrayItem.label !== this.state.selectedOption.label);
            LocationsActions.reloadDestinationList(filteredData)
        }
    }

    handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
        this.setState({ selectedOption });
        console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
        let location = this.state.selectedOption

        LocationsActions.setOrigin(location)//when I use this, got an error
    }

    handleChangeDestination = (selectedOption2) => {
        this.setState({ selectedOption2 });
        console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption2);
    }
    render() {


        if (this.props.type == "from") {
            const { selectedOption } = this.state;
            return (

                <div style={dropDownHolder} className="from-dropdown">
                    <div>
                        <h4>{this.props.title}</h4>
                    </div>

                    <Select
                        value={selectedOption}
                        defaultValue={this.props.selectedItem}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        options={this.props.originList}
                        onBlur={() => { this.filterDestinationList(this.props.originList) }}
                    />

                </div>
            );
        }
        if (this.props.type == "to") {
            const { selectedOption2 } = this.state;
            return (
                <div style={dropDownHolder} className="from-dropdown">
                    <div>
                        <h4>{this.props.title}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <Select
                        value={selectedOption2}
                        defaultValue={this.props.selectedItem}
                        onChange={this.handleChangeDestination}
                        options={this.props.destinationList}
                    />

                </div>)
        }
    }
}
export default Dropdown;
```

Comment: LocationsActions.setOrigin(location). That doesnt sound like something redux would be a familiar with. Where is this coming from? Is this a custom-function you built?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can

You need following steps:

Create an action type contatct e.g

```
const SET_FILTER = 'SET_FILTER';
```

Create an action

```
const setFilter = filter => dispatch({ type: SET_FILTER, payload: filter });
```

Handle this in reducer

```
case SET_FILTER:
  return {
    ...state,
    filter: action.payload
  }
```

Bind this action and value with your component where required

```
connect(state => ({ filter: state.someReducer.filter }), { setFilter: actions.setFilter })(YourComponent)
```

How you can set filter

```
this.props.setFilter(value);
```

This is how you can access that value in parent

```
this.props.filter
```

Comment: There is a huge misunderstanding. I just ask how can get value from state and put it to redux object. When I try this ı got an error

Comment: react-select.esm.js:4123 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of null

Comment: Answer is same, after setting state, dispatch an action, set value and get value in parent